# If a person has fought in a war, how do you describe them?

Tags: phrase-request

If a person has fought in a war, how do you describe them? Is 'to have combat experience' okay? It, I guess, wouldn't work with 'military experience' since it just means that a person has served in the military, not that he or she actually participated in a war battle. Don't suggest 'veteran'. It means, according to Lexico, "an ex-member of the armed forces", not exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't want [*veteran*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/veteran) as an answer, that **is** what's commonly used. While a *veteran* isn't necessarily somebody who actually fought, it's commonly thought of that way, despite its definition.

However, the *specific* term for somebody who's a veteran *and* who saw combat is **combat veteran**.

From ["What is a Combat Veteran?"](https://charliecompany.org/2013/01/07/what-is-a-combat-veteran/) at Charlie Company:

> **The American War Library states:**
>
> **What is a Veteran?** – A veteran is defined by federal law, moral code and military service as **“Any, Any, Any”…** A military veteran is **Any** person who served for **Any** length of time in **Any** military service branch.
>
> **What is a War Veteran?** – A war veteran is **Any** GI (Government Issue) ordered to foreign soil or waters to participate in direct or support activity against an enemy. The operant condition: Any **GI** sent in harm’s way.
>
> **What is a Combat Veteran?** – A combat veteran is **Any** GI who experiences any level of hostility for any duration resulting from offensive, defensive or friendly fire military action involving a real or perceived enemy in any foreign theater.  Wartime medals also define various levels of individual combat involvement, sacrifice and/or valor.

So, if you're being precise, the term you want is *combat veteran*.

Comment: What if I want a broader term/phrase? To include not only retired but also current members of armed forces

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev They are still *combat veterans*. But if you have to make the difference explicit, they could be described as *active duty combat veterans*, as opposed to *retired combat veterans*.